# Parsing elements from list into find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@href, "javascript") and contains(@href, '"(list1)[3]"')]')
```

I have code like that and its almost working.
The problem is when i have this part `'"(list1)[3]"'` i can write anything on place of 3 but Python will always take first element from list(index[0]) ignoring [x] after (list1).
How is this supposed to be writen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the 3rd item from the list like below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[starts-with(@href, 'javascript') and contains(@href, '{list1[3]}')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@href, "javascript") and contains(@href, "(list1)[3]")]')
```

In your expression you actually define the XPath expression as `//*[starts-with(@href, "javascript") and contains(@href,` , then concatinating another string `(list1)[3]` and then concatenating another string `)]`

Comment: I tried it at first and its not working at all. I just get Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Well, this means you are using a wrong locator. Van you share a link to that page or at least HTML containing all these elements?

Comment: cruisepandey method worked for me so i guess locator was fine. But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: This will never work, this is not the way we parse the list in Python.